# What is a good technique for making candy floss (cotton candy)?

Tags: equipment, candy

I have a candy floss machine, but I'm struggling to get the floss all together. It just flies around and makes a mess of the bowl.

It looks like this:

[image]

What is a good technique for making a stick of candy floss?

Comment: What machine do you have? Do you have a manual?

Comment: @Jolenealaska I have added a picture - it is the *"gourmet gadgetry candy floss maker"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this video on YouTube that happens to be exactly your product. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIMQ5moX37A. It just shows her using the machine, there is no explanation, but you might find it helpful. One thing I see right off the bat is that your little machine takes a lot longer than professional ones I've seen, but it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

It's been decades since I've done it, and it was with a full size professional machine (from a party rental store).  From what I remember:

- Wait for it to accumulate on the sides
- Reach in with a stick or a paper cone, down to the bottom of the spun sugar
- Pull up while scraping the stick along the side of the machine.

There was spinning involved, too.  I want to say that you spun the stick after you had the candy clear of the machine, not while it was in the machine, but my memory of that part is a bit hazy.

*Never* put your hand into the machine.  I don't know if it was the hot sugar getting flung off, or some sort of a straw nozzle flailing about, but whatever it is, it hurts.  (that much I remember).

It's possible that the procedure is different for smaller, personal machines.  For one, they don't tend to have as much space to accumulate the floss to make a full cone in one pass.

Answer (score 1):

I run the cotton candy machines for our Shriner Circus. What we do is wait for the floss to start forming on the sides, take a paper cone or stick and touch it to the floss. Then we start rotating it around the bowl opposite the direction it is being spun. You can also spin the stick or cone which may work better for you. Ours produces a lot of floss and it works better to circle the bowl.

Answer (score 0):

That model is considered a toy basically asking how to make a wedding cake in your EZ bake.

First let machine warm up for at least 3-5 minutes.

Second turn machine off and add sugar.  Preferably gold medals Floss sugar as it works the easiest.  Turn machine back on.

Now the toy aspect of the machine starts.  The spinner is small and the Floss holes are very few the bowl is also plastic.  It will come out very wispy and stick to the sides like glue.

Best you can hope for is a 1/4 to 1/2 size cone in around 2 minutes.  By spinning and small circles.

Comment: You give little information on the technique for making it. Most of this is a rant about the machine...

Comment: @Tim Pointing out that the results may not be as good as expected due to the quality of the machine explains why your results are so poor... Perhaps the wording could be better but it's still valid to point out... Other than the first sentence, the entire rest of the post seems to explain how to actually use it, though... Regardless, doesn't seem like that much of a "rant", merely a note that the results may not be as good as a professional machine.